Conditions refering to different times
Sometimes conditions in 1 conditional refer to the present not to the future. Right?

I will help you on condition that you ask me nicely- you are yet to ask

I will buy you a gift on condition that you help her- either once you help in the future or it may  refer to the present regular help and once I'm sure you help regularly I will buy you something



Both these examples would typically refer to the future. If your meaning is "If you do X, I'll do Y" then the implication is that it applies to the future, and using "on condition that" is the same. If you mean "regularly" or "if you continue to do X" then I'd expect that to be stated explicitly. You certainly can have conditions depending on past or present actions, but it doesn't make a lot of sense unless it's something I don't know about yet ("I will buy you a gift if your room is tidy" or "if you tidied your room" implies that I've not looked to see if your room is tidy).

I will buy a gift if your room is tidy could also refer to the futute condition, right?

Both your examples refer to the future.

I will help you on condition that you ask me nicely

I will help (in the future)....that you ask me nicely (also in the future).
Similarly for no.2
Referring has a double 'r' in the middle (even in America, I believe).
